# Running multiple tasks using SerialPort is increasing CPU usage % to 100% - is Thread.Sleep() a good way to solve?

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, sleep

I am building my own Airbus A320 home cockpit (see [here](https://forums.flightsimulator.com/t/simconnect-wasm-combined-project-using-vs2019/486871) and related links for more context). That means that I connect several HW-modules via USB to my computer, and each of one is being controlled and monitored by an application "CockpitHardwareHUB" (written in C#) which connects with Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 through their interfacing API called SimConnect.

My issue is that for each module I connect, my CPU Utilization increases by appx. 25%. I have a friend who also uses my software, and he connected a lot of modules, making the CPU Utilization clip to 100%. He says that he suffers performance loss.

**Questions**:

- Can somebody review my code concept (see below)?
- Is there a better way to communicate with my USB devices?
- Is adding "Thread.Sleep(5)" in my RxPump a good idea?

Here some more details about my code.

I wanted my software to detect when a module is connected or disconnected (hot swappable). There is no reliable way to do that with the SerialPort class, hence I used some low level concepts that I found on internet. I know, might be a bit tricky because it relies on some Windows internals that might change, but so far so good. Anyway, this is not my question, but just to give some context.

Once a module is connected to USB and detected, I create a "COMDevice" that handles all the Tx and Rx communication for that module. This COMDevice is launched as a separate Task using Task.Run(...).

Below is that section of the code that hooks in the WndProc of my main window. The code runs in an object "DeviceServer.cs" that keeps track of all connected devices. It detects if a USB device is connected or disconnected, verifies if it is one of my devices, and if it is creates a new COMDevice and launches it with Task.Run(...).

```
// WndProc hook to process USB Raw device Arrival or Deviceremovecomplete messages

public static void HandleWndProc(ref Message m)
{
    // Check if we got a device change message from a USB Raw device
    if (!_IsStarted || (m.Msg != Constants.WmDevicechange))
        return;

    // Check if a USB Raw device was inserted or removed
    Int32 msg = m.WParam.ToInt32();
    if (msg != Constants.DbtDevicearrival && msg != Constants.DbtDeviceremovecomplete)
        return;

    // Check if device change is for "Class of devices" (DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
    var devBroadcastDeviceInterface = new DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE();
    Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, devBroadcastDeviceInterface);
    if (devBroadcastDeviceInterface.dbcc_devicetype != Constants.DbtDevtypDeviceinterface)
        return;

    // Process the COMDevice Arrival or Deviceremovecomplete messages
    switch (msg)
    {
        case Constants.DbtDevicearrival:
            string PortName = COMDevice.GetPortNameFromPath(devBroadcastDeviceInterface.dbcc_name);
            COMDevice device = new COMDevice(devBroadcastDeviceInterface.dbcc_name, PortName); // default baudrate is 500000
            Task.Run(() => AddDevice(device));
            _Logger?.Invoke($"Devicearrival for {devBroadcastDeviceInterface.dbcc_name}", 0);
            break;

        case Constants.DbtDeviceremovecomplete:
            RemoveDevice(devBroadcastDeviceInterface.dbcc_name);
            _Logger?.Invoke($"Deviceremovecomplete for {devBroadcastDeviceInterface.dbcc_name}", 0);
            break;
    }
}
```

The method "AddDevice" which is called within the Task.Run(...) above, is Opening the device. If Opening is successful, "device.Initialize()" is called, which is really starting the communication pumps (see further below).

```
private static void AddDevice(COMDevice device)
{
    _Logger?.Invoke($"DeviceServer.AddDevice({device.Path})", 0);

    if (_devices.ContainsKey(device.Key))
        return;

    if (!device.Open())
        return;

    // Try a maximum of 20 times to connect with COMDevice
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        _Logger?.Invoke($"DeviceServer.AddDevice(): Try {i}", 0);
        if (device.Initialize())
        {
            _devices.TryAdd(device.Key, device);
            device.RegisterCommands();
            _DeviceAddRemove('+', device);
            //_DeviceNotification?.Invoke(device, new NotifyData(NotifyAction.deviceAdded));
            return;
        }
        else
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    // if we fail after 20 times, close the device
    device.Close();
}
```

Below are some extracts from the relevant methods in the object "COMDevice.cs". In the Initialize method, at the end, the 2 private local variables _TxPump and _RxPump are launched, also using a Task.Run(...) method. I also included the TxPump and RxPump methods which should give a high level view of what I'm doing.

```
public bool Open()
{
    try
    {
        _serialPort.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
            _serialPort.Close();
        Logger($"Open {_serialPort.PortName}: TimeoutException {ex}", 0);
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
            _serialPort.Close();
        Logger($"Open {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
        return false;
    }
}

public bool Close()
{
    if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
        return false;

    try
    {
        _serialPort.Write("RESET\n");
        _serialPort.Close();

        Task[] tasks = { _TxPump, _RxPump };
        return Task.WaitAll(tasks, 100);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger($"Close {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception  {ex}", 0);
        return false;
    }
}

private void ClearInputBuffer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int readCount = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
        if (readCount == 0)
            break;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[readCount];
        _serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }
}

public bool Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        // clean receive buffer of Arduino and this application
        _serialPort.Write("\n");
        ClearInputBuffer();

        // get identification
        _serialPort.Write("IDENT\n");
        _DeviceName = DeviceServer.GetUniqueDeviceName(_serialPort.ReadLine());
        _ProcessorType = _serialPort.ReadLine();
        Logger($"Initialize {_serialPort.PortName}: New Device found: IDENT = \"{_DeviceName}\" - \"{_ProcessorType}\"", 2);

        // counter for DeviceID
        int iDeviceID = 1;

        // register the LED/Data commands
        _serialPort.Write("REGISTER\n");
        while (true)
        {
            string sRegister = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RegisteredCmd rxCmd = new RegisteredCmd(sRegister, iDeviceID++);

            if (sRegister == "")
                break;
            Logger($"{_DeviceName}: REGISTER = \"{sRegister}\"", 2);
            _RegisteredCmds.Add(rxCmd);
        }
        Logger($"Initialize {_serialPort.PortName}: {_RegisteredCmds.Count} Commands Registered", 2);

        // start transmitting and receiving commands
        _TxPump = Task.Run(() => TxPump());
        _RxPump = Task.Run(() => RxPump());

        return true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Logger($"Initialize {_serialPort.PortName}: TimeoutException {ex}", 0);
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger($"Initialize {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
        return false;
    }
}

private void RxPump()
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder sbCmd = new StringBuilder("", 256);

    try
    {
        while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5); // see explanation below

            if (_serialPort.BytesToRead == 0)
                continue;

            int cnt = _serialPort.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);

            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                if ((char)buffer[i] == '\n')
                {
                    if ((sbCmd.Length == 1) && (sbCmd[0] == 'A'))
                        // ACK sequence received
                        _mreAck.Set();
                    else if (sbCmd.Length != 0)
                    {
                        // Command received - check if it has format 'NNN=...' and if it is a RegisteredCmd
                        string sCmd = sbCmd.ToString();
                        int iDeviceID = -1;
                        if ((sCmd.Length >= 4) && (sCmd[3] == '=') && int.TryParse(sCmd.Substring(0,3), out iDeviceID))
                        {
                            RegisteredCmd RegCmd = _RegisteredCmds.Find(x => x.iDeviceID == iDeviceID);
                            if (RegCmd != null)
                                sCmd = $"{RegCmd.iMSFSID:D03}{sCmd.Substring(3)}";
                            SendToMSFS(sCmd, true); // send to MSFS as registered command
                        }
                        else
                            SendToMSFS(sCmd, false); // send to MSFS as unregistered command
                        stats.cmdRxCnt++;
                    }
                    sbCmd.Clear();
                }
                else
                    sbCmd.Append((char)buffer[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger($"RxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
    }
}

private void TxPump()
{

    try
    {
        while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            string sCmd;

            if (_TxQueue.Count == 0)
                continue;
            else
                _TxQueue.TryDequeue(out sCmd);

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{sCmd}\n");

            int attempts = 2;

            while (attempts-- != 0)
            {
                _serialPort.BaseStream.Write(buffer, 0, sCmd.Length + 1);

                // Reset the ManualResetEvent and wait for ACK for 50 msec
                _mreAck.Reset();
                if (_mreAck.WaitOne(150))
                {
                    stats.cmdTxCnt++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    stats.nackCnt++;
                    Logger($"TxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Not Ack attempt {2 - attempts} for \"{sCmd}\"", 2);
                    // Send linefeed to be sure we are in sync
                    _serialPort.BaseStream.Write(LF, 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        while (_TxQueue.TryDequeue(out _));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger($"RxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
    }
}
```

The problem now is that when I connect devices, my CPU usage increases with almost 20% per device, until it clips to 100%. I have a friend who also uses my tool and has already a lot more devices, and he seems to suffer from performance issues.

The below pictures shows when I add 2 devices - MCDU (Multi-Function Control and Display Unit) and FCU (Flight Control Unit) - each time adding about 15% CPU Utilization.

[image]

Using Visual Studio 2022 analytical tools, I discover that most of the processor utilization is consumed in the TxPump and RxPump - which kind of makes sense I guess, as the TxPump and RxPump are continuously running.

[image]

I tried with adding "Thread.Sleep(5)" in the RxPump code, which already improved a lot. Processor utilization went from 40% to 25% when connecting my 2 devices. Thread.Sleep(5) is not blocking the CPU, but only the Thread, right? With other words, it is only blocking my "RxPump" for 5 msec, but keeps running the rest? Or is that too simplistic? Or am I mixing the terms Thread and Task here?

My friend told me that using "Thread.Sleep(5)" is a bad idea. He suggested a method that he uses a lot, and looks like something below:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static int _loop = 0; // Modifiable
    public static int _loopMAX = 0;
}
private void RxPump() 
{ 
     var buffer = new byte[1024] 
     StringBuilder sbCmd = new StringBuilder("", 256); 
  

     // Throttle Logic 
     _loop += 1; 
     if (_loop >= _loopMAX) 
     { 
         _loop = 0; 
     } 
  
     if (_Loop == 0) 
     { 
         try
         { 
             while (_serialPort.IsOpen) 
             { ... The rest of your code    

             }
         }    
     }
}
```

In my opinion, using Thread.Sleep(5) is as good (or as bad) as his proposal?

**EDIT 10-OCT-2023**

As suggested in one of the comments, I used the async methods. Below you see both the sync and async way of working in one block of code (async has been commented).

Basically I have changed the RxPump and TxPump methods into RxPumpAsync and TxPumpAsync. In the Async versions of the methods, I have used the "await _serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync" and "await _serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync". To improve comparison, I have removed the Thread.Sleep() call in the synchronous version.

```
public bool Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        // clean receive buffer of Arduino and this application
        _serialPort.Write("\n");
        ClearInputBuffer();

        // get identification
        _serialPort.Write("IDENT\n");
        _DeviceName = DeviceServer.GetUniqueDeviceName(_serialPort.ReadLine());
        _ProcessorType = _serialPort.ReadLine();
        Logger($"Initialize {_serialPort.PortName}: New Device found: IDENT = \"{_DeviceName}\" - \"{_ProcessorType}\"", 2);

        // counter for DeviceID
        int iDeviceID = 1;

        // register the LED/Data commands
        _serialPort.Write("REGISTER\n");
        while (true)
        {
            string sRegister = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RegisteredCmd rxCmd = new RegisteredCmd(sRegister, iDeviceID++);

            if (sRegister == "")
                break;
            Logger($"{_DeviceName}: REGISTER = \"{sRegister}\"", 2);
            _RegisteredCmds.Add(rxCmd);
        }
        Logger($"Initialize {_serialPort.PortName}: {_RegisteredCmds.Count} Commands Registered", 2);

        // start transmitting and receiving commands
        _TxPump = Task.Run(() => TxPump());
        _RxPump = Task.Run(() => RxPump());
        //_TxPump = Task.Run(() => TxPumpAsync());
        //_RxPump = Task.Run(() => RxPumpAsync());

        return true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Logger($"Initialize {_serialPort.PortName}: TimeoutException {ex}", 0);
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger($"Initialize {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
        return false;
    }
}

private void RxPump()
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder sbCmd = new StringBuilder("", 256);

    try
    {
        while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(5);

            if (_serialPort.BytesToRead == 0)
                continue;

            int cnt = _serialPort.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);

            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                if ((char)buffer[i] == '\n')
                {
                    if ((sbCmd.Length == 1) && (sbCmd[0] == 'A'))
                        // ACK sequence received
                        _mreAck.Set();
                    else if (sbCmd.Length != 0)
                    {
                        // Command received - check if it has format 'NNN=...' and if it is a RegisteredCmd
                        string sCmd = sbCmd.ToString();
                        int iDeviceID = -1;
                        if ((sCmd.Length >= 4) && (sCmd[3] == '=') && int.TryParse(sCmd.Substring(0, 3), out iDeviceID))
                        {
                            RegisteredCmd RegCmd = _RegisteredCmds.Find(x => x.iDeviceID == iDeviceID);
                            if (RegCmd != null)
                                sCmd = $"{RegCmd.iMSFSID:D03}{sCmd.Substring(3)}";
                            SendToMSFS(sCmd, true); // send to MSFS as registered command
                        }
                        else
                            SendToMSFS(sCmd, false); // send to MSFS as unregistered command
                        stats.cmdRxCnt++;
                    }
                    sbCmd.Clear();
                }
                else
                    sbCmd.Append((char)buffer[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger($"RxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
    }
}

private void TxPump()
{
    try
    {
        while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            string sCmd;

            if (_TxQueue.Count == 0)
                continue;
            else
                _TxQueue.TryDequeue(out sCmd);

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{sCmd}\n");

            int attempts = 2;

            while (attempts-- != 0)
            {
                _serialPort.BaseStream.Write(buffer, 0, sCmd.Length + 1);

                // Reset the ManualResetEvent and wait for ACK for 50 msec
                _mreAck.Reset();
                if (_mreAck.WaitOne(150))
                {
                    stats.cmdTxCnt++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    stats.nackCnt++;
                    Logger($"TxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Not Ack attempt {2 - attempts} for \"{sCmd}\"", 2);
                    // Send linefeed to be sure we are in sync
                    _serialPort.BaseStream.Write(LF, 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        while (_TxQueue.TryDequeue(out _)) ;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger($"RxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
    }
}

//private async Task RxPumpAsync()
//{
//    var buffer = new byte[1024];
//    StringBuilder sbCmd = new StringBuilder("", 256);

//    try
//    {
//        while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
//        {
//            if (_serialPort.BytesToRead == 0)
//                continue;

//            int cnt = await _serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);

//            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
//            {
//                if ((char)buffer[i] == '\n')
//                {
//                    if ((sbCmd.Length == 1) && (sbCmd[0] == 'A'))
//                        // ACK sequence received
//                        _mreAck.Set();
//                    else if (sbCmd.Length != 0)
//                    {
//                        // Command received - check if it has format 'NNN=...' and if it is a RegisteredCmd
//                        string sCmd = sbCmd.ToString();
//                        int iDeviceID = -1;
//                        if ((sCmd.Length >= 4) && (sCmd[3] == '=') && int.TryParse(sCmd.Substring(0, 3), out iDeviceID))
//                        {
//                            RegisteredCmd RegCmd = _RegisteredCmds.Find(x => x.iDeviceID == iDeviceID);
//                            if (RegCmd != null)
//                                sCmd = $"{RegCmd.iMSFSID:D03}{sCmd.Substring(3)}";
//                            SendToMSFS(sCmd, true); // send to MSFS as registered command
//                        }
//                        else
//                            SendToMSFS(sCmd, false); // send to MSFS as unregistered command
//                        stats.cmdRxCnt++;
//                    }
//                    sbCmd.Clear();
//                }
//                else
//                    sbCmd.Append((char)buffer[i]);
//            }
//        }
//    }
//    catch (Exception ex)
//    {
//        Logger($"RxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
//    }
//}

//private async Task TxPumpAsync()
//{
//    try
//    {
//        while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
//        {
//            string sCmd;

//            if (_TxQueue.Count == 0)
//                continue;
//            else
//                _TxQueue.TryDequeue(out sCmd);

//            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{sCmd}\n");

//            int attempts = 2;

//            while (attempts-- != 0)
//            {
//                await _serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, sCmd.Length + 1);

//                // Reset the ManualResetEvent and wait for ACK for 50 msec
//                _mreAck.Reset();
//                if (_mreAck.WaitOne(150))
//                {
//                    stats.cmdTxCnt++;
//                    break;
//                }
//                else
//                {
//                    stats.nackCnt++;
//                    Logger($"TxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Not Ack attempt {2 - attempts} for \"{sCmd}\"", 2);
//                    // Send linefeed to be sure we are in sync
//                    _serialPort.BaseStream.Write(LF, 0, 1);
//                }
//            }
//        }

//        while (_TxQueue.TryDequeue(out _)) ;
//    }
//    catch (Exception ex)
//    {
//        Logger($"RxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
//    }
//}
```

If I now compare the CPU Usage of both versions, I don't see a difference at all.

Synchronous version
[image]

Asynchronous version
[image]

My guess is that the issue is not caused by the SerialPort communication, but is caused by the TxPump and RxPump itself that is running in an endless loop:

```
while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
{
   ...
}
```

For every device I'm adding, I add a TxPump and RxPump task that is running in an endless loop. Could this be the reason of my processor usage going through the roof? Maybe I should find an async method to deal with these endless loops, and use await until characters are being received or sent? I'm not really expert in asynchronous methods, but I think that is the solution?

I have created another post for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266588/how-to-make-a-cpu-friendly-transmit-and-receive-pump-using-serialport-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Never use Synchronous methods with serial port on Windows.  It is best to modify code and use Asynchronous methods,  You can then eliminate the sleep. I block application so it does not close using WaitOne.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-7.0

Comment: Thanks @jdweng - Actually, I had built this earlier using async methods, but I had some other issues then. Maybe I should find this code back and try again.
Still, would like to know if Thread.Sleep(..) is a good way to keep the RxPump from occupying the processor too much, or is this just a dumb idea?

Comment: The buffers can overflow or you can end up with large latency