# How to make a CPU-friendly Transmit and Receive Pump using SerialPort in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, serial-port

I am building my own Airbus A320 home cockpit (see [here](https://forums.flightsimulator.com/t/simconnect-wasm-combined-project-using-vs2019/486871) and related links for more context). That means that I connect several HW-modules via USB to my computer, and each of one is being controlled and monitored by an application "CockpitHardwareHUB" (written in C#) which connects with Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 through their interfacing API called SimConnect.

My issue is that for each module I connect, my CPU Utilization increases by appx. 25%. I have a friend who also uses my software, and he connected a lot of modules, making the CPU Utilization clip to 100%. He says that he suffers performance loss.

Earlier, I asked a question on this forum related to the same topic: "[Running multiple tasks using SerialPort is increasing CPU usage % to 100% - is Thread.Sleep() a good way to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162833/running-multiple-tasks-using-serialport-is-increasing-cpu-usage-to-100-is-t)"

There, somebody (@jdweng) commented:

> Never use Synchronous methods with serial port on Windows. It is best to modify code and use Asynchronous methods.

I did that, and added it as an EDIT in my post on 10-Oct-2023. But there was no difference at all. But this made me realize that the issue has probably nothing to do with SerialPort itself, but the way I built my RxPump and TxPump. Let me explain.

In some initialize method I use the below code to create a RxPump and a TxPump. This is done for each hardware module I connect - with other words, for every module I have a TxPump and RxPump running.

```
_TxPump = Task.Run(() => TxPump());
_RxPump = Task.Run(() => RxPump());
```

In my TxPump and RxPump, I have an endless loop that looks like below:

```
private void RxPump()
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];

    try
    {
        while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            if (_serialPort.BytesToRead == 0)
                continue;

            int cnt = _serialPort.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);

            ... rest of code
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger($"RxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
    }
}

private void TxPump()
{
    try
    {
        while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            string sCmd;

            if (_TxQueue.Count == 0)
                continue;
            else
                _TxQueue.TryDequeue(out sCmd);

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{sCmd}\n");

            _serialPort.BaseStream.Write(buffer, 0, sCmd.Length + 1);

            ... rest of code
        }

        while (_TxQueue.TryDequeue(out _)) ;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger($"RxPump {_serialPort.PortName}: Exception {ex}", 0);
    }
}
```

**QUESTION1**: Looking at my code, it means that in each Pump I have simply an endless loop "While(true) {}" as long as the SerialPort is open. Could that be the cause of my CPQ Usage going out of the roof?

**QUESTION2**: Can somebody help me with a more elegant method that uses the Async methodology, and that instead of keeping the Pump running in an endless loop, uses an async await methodology?

- In the RxPump, the Await should wait until characters are being received - process them - and then go back in the Await state waiting for the next characters
- In the TxPump, the Await should wait until there is a command available in the _TxQueue (this is a ConcurrentQueue) - send it - and then go back in the Await state waiting for the next command

Comment: An infinite loop that never relinquishes the CPU (e.g. use a blocking syscall) is a CPU hog. Such a process would force the scheduler to suspend it, and you could see high CPU utilization.  The concept of multiprocessing relies on each process either not being compute bound, or able to suspend itself to allow another process is be scheduled to execute.  Async and nonblocking I/O schemes are misplaced attempts in userspace to control/hog the CPU at the expense of other processes.  CPU control is best handled by the multitasking OS, and using threads and/or blocking I/O in userspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking at my code, it means that in each Pump I have simply an endless loop "While(true) {}" as long as the SerialPort is open. Could that be the cause of my CPQ Usage going out of the roof?

Yes, this is a form of "spin wait", and will in practice use up a CPU core per receiver or sender.

> In the RxPump, the Await should wait until characters are being received - process them - and then go back in the Await state waiting for the next characters

One option would be to use [DataReceived event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). Another alternative would be to just skip the `_serialPort.BytesToRead == 0` and always run "Read" instead, that should block until there is something in the receive buffer. Remember to handle exceptions, especially `TimeoutException`, and optionally set the `ReadTimeout` .

> In the TxPump, the Await should wait until there is a command available in the _TxQueue (this is a ConcurrentQueue) - send it - and then go back in the Await state waiting for the next command

Use a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-7.0) instead:

```
foreach(var sCmd in _TxQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()){..}
```

This will block the thread while there are nothing in the queue. And you can use `CompleteAdding()` to terminate the loop in a convenient and threadsafe way, just remember to wait for the task it runs in to ensure everthing has been sent.

A note on async/await. Synchronous code works just fine if you actually block the thread while waiting for data and not just spin waiting. Asynchronous code can save some resources, i.e. memory, and that can certainly be a good thing. But I'm guessing you are running a few such modules, not hundreds, so I would not expect much of a practical difference. So if you are comfortable with async/await, go ahead and use some asynchronous queue, and `serialport.BaseStream.ReadAsync`. But if you are not I would recommend sticking to synchronous code running on background threads/tasks.

You might also want to read [If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)

Comment: I like your async read suggestion - that means that I will get a lot of timeouts, but these can then retrigger the read, right? It also means a kind of loop (try/catch), but it's not running continuously due to the await of the read. About the BlockingCollection, I have no clue what this is. But do you mean that "blocking" a thread is more forgiving to the CPU usage than simply having a while(true) loop? I thought that both are kind of "blocking" the same way? Or do I see that wrong?

Comment: Blocking collection should help, but your code already has blocking semantics, ie your `_serialPort.BaseStream.Read` call is a blocking call. So, i believe the root of all evil here is `if (_serialPort.BytesToRead == 0) continue;` that makes your loop hot like a hell's boiler. `BytesToRead == 0` only means that your receive queue is empty, ie your receiver grabs data quite fast, it doesn't mean you should continue the loop. Just remove that line. Btw, moving to async world makes your code to employ threads much more effectively. Both solutions are better than looping that hell's wheel.)

Comment: @Ryan I think I start getting it. It's better to "block" a call, rather then keep it running in a loop, right? But that means that I will get a timeout exception, which I then need to catch and restart the loop, correct? I can easily do that by removing the lines you mentioned above in the RxPump, and can use BlockingCollection in the TxPump. Sounds like a plan!

Comment: @HansBilliet "Blocking" in this context means the thread is marked as "waiting", and the the scheduler will not schedule the thread until whatever it is waiting for happens, so it will not consume any CPU time. Ideally you should have some form of heartbeat to signal that communication is working, then you can simply set the timeout to be larger than this interval. If you lack this you probably need to add a try/catch inside the loop that just ignore timeout exceptions.

Comment: @HansBilliet, yep, that's correct, blocking, in short, means thread is not using CPUs resources. As answer above mentiones, it is kinda spin-based synchronization primitive, which works improperly, ie too long and *fry chips* phenomena is being observed. Btw, could you just make timeout infinite here?

Comment: Several people have contributed to the answer. I did a first experiment by 1) removing "_serialPort.BytesToRead == 0" in the RxPump and 2) using BlockingCollection in the TxPump, and the result is that there is no noticeable increase in CPU usage anymore when I connect one or more modules. THANKS A MILLION for the good advice. I learned a lot!